# get secret from secrets manager returns none | elastic beanstalk | flask

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-secrets-manager

**Problem:** `get_secret()` returns none.

**Landscape:**

AWS provides a template function which works fine locally when I try it out in the terminal.

**What I have done:**

I added `return json.loads(get_secret_value_response["SecretString"])` so `get_secret()` returns a value if successful.

I have **attached a policy to the secret** in secrets manager.

```
{
  "Version" : "2012-10-17",
  "Statement" : [ {
    "Effect" : "Allow",
    "Principal" : {
      "AWS" : "arn:aws:iam::__owner_id__:role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-service-role"
    },
    "Action" : "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
    "Resource" : "*"
  } ]
}
```

and I have **attached a policy to the role** `aws-elasticbeanstalk-service-role`.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:eu-west-1:__owner_id__:secret:route/to/scret-123"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: How do you expect us to help without seeing the full python code?

Comment: get_secret() is a function template, provided by AWS when the secret is created, which I didn't write so I didn't include it as I assumed the issue to be on my side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`aws-elasticbeanstalk-service-role` is for EB service itself. You should be using role associated with your [EB instance profile](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts-roles-instance.html). The default role is `aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role`, but you may have used different role in your setup, so you have to double check that.